# How to catch TwitterApiException when there is a time out in SearchTimeline request?(Android)

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitter-search

I'm implementing a SearchTimeline in android using the TwitterUI kit, Its working fine except I couldn't find a way to handle Timeout error or no connection error thrown when loading more tweets. Any idea how to handle these exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in [TimelineDelegate.java](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/internal/TimelineDelegate.java), you can see there is no CallBack set with PreviousCallback.
Unfortunately...

Maybe you could clone their git and modify this.

Comment: In the end this is exactly what I did, I downloaded the library and did some customizations so that it uses a recycler view instead of listview and did a success and error callback on the timeline, and also a custom view for tweets. Thanks!